# function object doesn't recognize the param(std::set<int>) that it gets

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl

I'm trying to write a template function that uses a function object.
the param that the function object get is `std::set` (type `int`).
for some reason, when I'm trying to go throw the set with: `for(auto curr: set)`, it doesn't even go into the for loop, like it doesn't recognize it's a stl set!

MAIN:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Functor object_x;
    SetInt set_1={1,2,6,4,3};
    SetInt set_output;

    set_output=mtmAlgorithem_2(set_output ,set_1,object_x);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the template:

```cpp
template < typename SetToReturn,typename Generic, typename Functor >

SetToReturn mtmAlgorithem_2(SetToReturn a,Generic input, Functor object){

//All elements after element X including X.
    SetToReturn after_x;
    //All elements before element X not-including X.
    SetToReturn before_x;
    //Output set
    SetToReturn output;

    //copy elements from input to after_x:
    for(auto element: input){
        after_x.insert(element);
    }

    for(auto element: input){


// > ---------THIS IS WERE I CALL THE FUNCTION OBJECT------

        if(object(before_x,after_x)){
            output.insert(element);
        }
        before_x.erase(element);
        after_x.insert(element);
    }
    return output;
}
```

This is the function object:

```cpp
class Functor
{
    public:
        bool operator()( SetInt &before_x, SetInt &after_x){
            bool res=true;
            for(int curr_1: before_x){


//------------not getting here---------------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                for(int curr_2: after_x){
                    if(curr_1>curr_2){
                        res=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            std::cout<<"lla"<<std::endl;
            return res;
        };
};
```

Comment: Where is `SetInt` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never put anything into `before_x` so of course that loop doesn't do anything.